# HTML Style Guide Google vs W3Schools (Omit Optional Tag)

Tags: html

I was reading some style guides and saw a conflicting recommendation
regarding the optional tags.

Google says:

> Omit optional tags (optional). For file size optimization and
> scannability purposes, consider omitting optional tags. The HTML5
> specification defines what tags can be omitted.
>
> (This approach may require a grace period to be established as a wider
> guideline as it’s significantly different from what web developers are
> typically taught. For consistency and simplicity reasons it’s best
> served omitting all optional tags, not just a selection.)

W3Schools says:

> Close All HTML Elements In HTML5, you don't have to close all elements
> (for example the `<p>` element).
>
> We recommend closing all HTML elements:

And

> We do not recommend omitting the < html > and < body > tags.

This means Google prefers:

```
<!-- Recommended -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Saving money, saving bytes</title>
<p>Qed.
```

W3Schools prefers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Page Title</title>

<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

it is also considered "bad looking" to write this whereas google would recommend it.

```
<section>
  <p>This is a paragraph.
  <p>This is a paragraph.
</section>
```

I found it very interesting that W3Schools makes a difference regarding the head tag

**Is there any good reason to stop using the optional tags?**
Personally I found the code then less readable but that is purely opinion based and I guess with some training I would prefer one over the other.

Google stated that its for size optimization and scannability purposes but is that really a good reason? The articles below stated some suggestions but seemed to me more opinion based and I am looking for good reasons to stop using the optional tags

Here the resources:

1. [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html)
2. [HTML5 Style Guide](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp)
3. [html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags)
4. [Omitting optional tags of html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585217/omitting-optional-tags-of-html)

Comment: You refer to the W3C but none of your links are to the W3C. You do include one to W3Schools which, if you didn't know, is entirely unrelated to the W3C.

Comment: You are right my mistake

Comment: Yes. That is the W3Schools opinion on this. And Google has their opinion.

Comment: Changed the title and text

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, don't rely on w3schools. While they have gotten better over the last year or so, they are notorious for providing false information and bad practices.

Comment: @DrewKennedy That was the past. W3Schools is fine. No worse than most sites. Better than some. Yes, there are better.

Comment: Removing closing tag only give confusion on large file. It is bad for readability. And some bots scanning the HTML File for indexing may really not like it. This is like really micr-optimization. Those exists but just make things more complicated, unreadable. Only use them when you're really sure that you need them. And i don't think you need the closing tag thing.

Comment: I generally close most tags, where appropriate. It is far more readable. Or at least close them with `/>`, if it's a standalone tag such as input, img or meta. So, `<img src="/path/to/image" />`. I think that general rule is a little more relaxed now though.

Comment: The point about a style guide is, which ever one you choose to use, for best readability, be consistent and follow that guide throughout all your pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many times we use the optional closing tags because it makes the document more readable. As Google says, removing them reduces file size but, then, most of us don't have the traffic Google does. That suggestion is for those who do. Then, again, reducing download size is always a good thing.

I often leave out the body tag altogether because even the opening tag is optional in most cases. However, there is a danger that leaving that out, and leaving out closing tags, may cause issues later on. I would say putting body tags in and closing all elements removes the possibility of causing those issues. For example, you can only leave the html and body tags out under certain situations.

[Reading the spec:](https://developers.whatwg.org/semantics.html#the-html-element)

> An html element's start tag can be omitted if the first thing inside
>   the html element is not a comment. An html element's end tag can be
>   omitted if the html element is not immediately followed by a comment.

For some, this is very important. To others it's not.

It can be more of an issue for dynamically generated sites where the content is created on the fly and the surrounding elements may not be known. Does one really know that the following element will cause a div element to be closed?

Comment: I left the question intentionally open for several days to see if there were some differing opinions. I found the argument with the dynamically generated code convincing

Answer (score 1):

Another opinion:

If your site uses gzip compression, DO go out of your way to include the optional tags, speaking at least if in very large tables where so many cell tags are repeated.

If omitted, the original file size is smaller, but then the receiving browser just has to spend time putting every optional tag back in.  They will be in the displayed html file.  Look at the displayed page source and you will see this is true. So omission is a balance of faster download speed and slower display recovery speed.

But if gzip and the tags are included, gzip compression will compress away the repeated tags, and the transmitted file is no larger than if not included (so absolutely no download savings). And then the browser does not have to spend any time adding every one of them back in.  And they ARE going to be added back in.  And if hundreds or more cells in a table, this time might add up.

So if gzip, omitting HTML optional tags seems a minus for speed, not a plus (certainly at least in the case of very large tables).  Your web host likely provides an feature to add gzip compression.

Single tags like /body or /tbody can't matter to speed, but /td and /tr can be very numerous in large tables.